# Как подключить API Binance?

Tags: python, api

У меня стоит задача подключить API Binance p2p и выполнить с его помощью следующие задачи:

1. Получение списка продавцов на Binance p2p
2. Сортировка списка продавцов и получение информации по ним
3. Отслеживание состояния продавцов и перевод валюты в нужную мне

Сейчас у меня есть этот код

```
import json
import requests

key = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT"

data = requests.get(key)
data = data.json()
print(f"{data['symbol']} price is {data['price']}")
```

Через него я получаю данные по валюте. Мне же нужно получить данные с этой страницы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные обведенные красным за исключением кол-ва валюты у продавца мне нужно задавать, а само кол-во валюты мне нужно получать. Можете подсказать, как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Прочитай API https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#market-data-endpoints